# Most efficient to prevent duplicates

Tags: postgresql

I'm building an application that will fetch messages with JSON every once in a while and store these in a postgres db. Now I want to prevent duplicates, so I calculate the sha-512 of the message and set it as the primary key. Since I want to prevent duplicates I can do two things:

1. Fetch all hashes from the database and see when inserting new messages if the hash already exists (checking in code)
2. Use an insert ignore (in postgres an update probably, since postgres doesn't support insert ignore) and let the database handle these exceptions

Considering I will probably be inserting a few messages at a time, I was wondering if method two will look up the primary key and see if exists for every insert as opposed to just storing a list in memory with method 1. What would be the most efficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't have `INSERT ... IGNORE` so that isn't an option. You can use upsert-like operations (search for "postgresql upsert) but they certainly have a performance cost. Inserting and ignoring the resulting error on duplicate key is possible, but it tends to result in pretty spammy logs.

Personally, I'd do what's effectively do a bulk upsert, where I'd do something like this:

- `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE staging_table(...)`
- `COPY TO staging_table(...) FROM ...` (or do bulk inserts)
- `LOCK TABLE real_table IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`
- `INSERT INTO real_table(...) SELECT col1,col2,col3,... FROM staging_table WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM real_table WHERE real_table.primarykey = staging_table.primarykey)`
- `COMMIT`

You can do an `UPDATE` before the `INSERT` if you want, updating existing records with new values.

The `LOCK TABLE` is necessary to prevent concurrent updates failing with errors. You can still `SELECT` from the table during the update.

If you `EXPLAIN` the plan for your `INSERT` you should see that it's been transformed into a `JOIN` when you're inserting larger numbers of records.

Comment: Missed a spot: there can be duplicates in the staging table itself, which would not be detected this way and lead to a unique key violation as well. Use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` with the `SELECT ... FROM staging_table`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Very good point. Can't really handle that without knowing the data (do you just `DISTINCT ON` and pick the 1st? Pick the one that's chronologically last? etc) but that case certainly must be handled.